# Where can I find the info regarding how many answers were deleted in a given period of time for not having sources?

Tags: support, answers, sources-and-citations

I can see lots of answers on the Main site are having the citation needed banner.

I guess the purpose behind this banner is to let the concerned users know that their answers are going to be deleted after "sometime" unless they are being able to support their answers with the sources.

So, understandably, deletion of un-sourced answers must be happening all the time.

So the question is - Where I can find the info like how many answers were deleted over (say) the last month for not having sources?

Comment: Why can't i add a "deleted-answers" tag here?

Comment: Because [meta-tag:deleted-answers] and [meta-tag:answers] are synonyms as of today. Ideally they both should be totally different tags. Regarding the main post, it's a good question. This has been raised in past in different forms. It's not possible to find the deleted post for self or others. But it could be easy to find, the posts with citation-banner, which are not yet deleted.

Answer (score 3):

### It is in the [Moderator Tools](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tools).

We can't know if an answer was deleted for a specific reason unless it is deleted as Rude/Abusive or Spam. We can only know if a moderator ad specified a reason in the comment section why he is deleting. We can know easily if it is a pure question, edit or comment (According to SE standards.. not our sites) posted in answers but if they do it for lacking sources, they generally leave a comment.

Users with [access to Moderator tools](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) i.e., with >2k reputation can look at some interesting stats, closed posts deleted posts within a range of 30 days. These are popularly known as 10k tools as they are gained at 10k on normal sites.

[image: Image focusing tools from the drop down]

Deletion of unsourced answers is not happening all the time. Moderators are giving enough time for older answers to update with sources. If there is no response from the other side, they are deleting them. It is happening rarely. But the same is not happening with new users and new posts. Users should consider that giving time for new users too. They are flagging the answers for citation banners or Very Low Quality straight away without educating new users how site works or how answers are to be written. This way should change and we have to give some time for them too.