# What is the policy on unverifiable, extravagant claims in answers?

Tags: support

In this

[Is it possible for the Vedas to have been authored?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32779/is-it-possible-for-the-vedas-to-have-been-authored?rq=1)

answer, it is said

> But as a matter of fact, before the kali yuga, people believed that the Vedas were authored by the Rishis. For example, the extremely ancient Yaska, author of the Nirukta, says in the Nirukta:

> 1.20 - The rishis were the ones who had a direct vision Dharma. For the sake of the inferior people who were not endowed with a vision of Dharma, [the rishis] gave mantras as instruction/teaching. This is the Veda and Vedāṅgas.

> 7.3 - Thus, the visions of the rishis occur with various intentions and topics.

> **Yaska lived in a previous yuga.**

If the bolded part is not backed up by scripture, it is an extravagant claim that lowers the tone of HSE.

What is the policy on such clams?

Answer (score 4):

If an answer makes certain claims that are just opinions and not backed up with (allowed) sources, like scriptures, then one can flag the answer using "in need of moderator intervention".

In the text box you can write something like:

The claim " ........ " made in this answer needs citation and is currently not backed up. If your claim is valid a Mod will add a "citation needed banner" to that answer.

> If answer doesn't cite any sources or references, comment and/or
> citation notice will be added to the answer.

The above is quoted from [this answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/827/4732).

Answer (score 0):

If an answer is answering the question but has other useless info which is unnecessary claims or personal opinions, then

- The high rep users can edit the answer to remove such content. Provide edit reason clearly to keep things clear.
- Low rep users can flag and explain the same.

If the whole answer is  "not answering the question" then

- Try Informing the user to provide the citation
- Flag it as "not an answer" rather than editing the post. Or flag to mods with comment if you feel an explanation is needed.

Comment: But some unfounded and/or extreme sectarian views are very dear to some posters and there will only be an edit ping-pong if a non-moderator were to  directly edit their content.  The evidence is overwhelming that certain kinds of inappropriate material are next to impossible to remove at HSE @mr_green .

Comment: If it is ping-pong, flag for the mod's attention.

Answer (score -2):

There is only one way - but it is unlikely that it will be implemented.

It should be possible to say "support this statement with a citation within X days, or it will be deleted".

there are citation banners that are years old on which nothing gets done.

Comment: You may find the [info here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2181/93).